# Content of website is Centralise in HTML Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, containers

There are many website's content are centralize.

I guess they use container or some custom container class to proceed that.
But is there any standard about that?
1440px, 1010px, 760px of those container is some standard?

Why they have to do that, is it for better looking or have another purpose?

Thanks

ps I am a beginner of html,css,php sorry about that :)

Comment: This is needed when user might view the website on different screens like desktop, tablet, mobile phone of different screen size

Comment: @Andrew Li Can you fix your grammar please (such as "content are centralize")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -2):

```css
You may define your own css like
.container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 40%;
        }
```